# Expect doesn't execute script in screen

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, gnu-screen

I'm trying to execute a script in `screen` through `expect` with `ssh`, but it's never executed. I know this because I do not see a `screen` session with `screen -list`. `Expect`s' exit code is 0. If I execute the command through SSH manually, it works.

What am I doing wrong? (Other ways to achieve my goal are welcome as well).

The script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
expect -d <<-EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh ${user}@${host}
    expect {
        "yes/no" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
        "password: " { send "${pass}\r" }
    }
    expect "*# "
    send "screen -dm bash -c './${CLIENT_SCRIPT_LOG}'\r"
    exit 0
EOF
exit $?
```

Debug output:

```
[.. cut ..]
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nLinux client 4.9.76-Rxx-rt61-gb7ccafd-dirty #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Apr 1 13:14:00 CEST 2020 armv7l\r\n\r\nThe programs included with the Debian GLinux system are free software;\r\nthe exact distribution terms for each program are described in the\r\nindividual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.\r\n\r\nDebian GNU/Linux cs with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent\r\npermitted by applicable law.\r\nLast login: Thu Jan  1 05:29:03 1970 from 192.168.138.2\r\r\nroot@client:~# "
send: sending "screen -dm bash -c './log.sh'\r" to { exp5 }
```

Versions client:
- Debian Wheezy
- Bash 4.2.37
- Screen 4.01.00devel

Versions host:
 - Debian Stretch
 - Bash 4.4.12(1)-release
 - Screen version 4.05.0
 - Expect 5.45

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it seems that I have to wait until the command is executed and exit the terminal. I think expect is too fast otherwise.

```sh
send "screen -dm bash -c './${CLIENT_SCRIPT_LOG}'\r"
expect "*# " { send "exit\r" }
exit 0
```

Comment: I'd recommend your last line be `expect eof` to allow ssh to exit gracefully.